# Running same query in 2 different views: What's the proper way?

Tags: laravel

Just getting started into laravel and need to run the same db query for 2 different views, I know I could just create 2 controllers and perform the same query in both passing it to each view.
But, is that the proper way? Or is there a way without repeating my code?

Thanks!

Edit:

I have the following function inside a controller:

```
protected function getLocation($url)
{
    $match = ['url' => $url];
    $location = DB::table('location')->where($match)->first();
    if (!$location) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $location;
}
```

the controller is returning that data to a view:

```
public function showsubcatandlocation($service)
{
    $category = $this->getCat($service);
    $location = $this->getLocation($category);
    $id = $category->id;
    $locID = $location->id;
    $profiles = $this->getProfileswLoc($id, $locID);
    return view('category', ['profile' => $profiles]);
}
```

What's the proper way to reuse the getLocation function? Or should I just copy it in the new controller? I just need to use it in those 2 views.

Comment: On stackoverflow we want code examples, so we can provide a concise answer, what query do you want to run in context of what models etc.

Comment: If you don't show any code is hard to give an advice. If this helps, this could be suited for [View composers](https://laravel.com/docs/views#view-composers).

Comment: Edited with code

Answer (score 0):

maybe `scope Query` helps?

```php
class Location extends Model
{
    public function scopeMatch($query, $url)
    {
        return $query->where('url', $url);
    }
}
```

And then your two controllel methods will be

```php
    $location = Task::match($url)->first();
    if (!$location) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $location;
```

```php
    $category = $this->getCat($service);
    $location = Task::match($category['url'])->first();
    $id = $category->id;
    $locID = $location->id;
    $profiles = $this->getProfileswLoc($id, $locID);

    return view('category', ['profile' => $profiles]);
```